# Example of computation of S matrix

Tags: rf, electromagnetism, electromagnetic, microwave

Let's consider the slide 1 of [this](http://arpg-serv.ing2.uniroma1.it/mostacci/didattica/lab-elettronica-I/LezioneDD_matriceS/03_Excercise_MatrixCalculus_2019.pdf) material.

I have understood the computation of S11, but not that of S21.

[image]

I do not understand:
- why there is the circuit with V and two impedances Z0 and there is not Zx. What does this circuit represent?

- Why then it considers the circuit with also Zx.
- Why the source is added together with an output impedance (Z0): I have seen examples of computation of S parameters by adding only an ideal voltage source, without output impedance.

Comment: Can you post the circuit for which you are finding S matrix?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand where the 2 factor, as in 2/V, came from.  The equation for b2 looks right.  The S21 in the network below should just be Zo/(2*Zo+Zx).

[image]

Comment: I know this is old, but this answer cannot be right.  As \$Z_x\to 0\$ then \$S_{21} \to 1\$.